# I'm having a hard time with pointers and dynamic arrays

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Edit: Thanks for all of the feedback! I have changed sizeof for strlen, thanks for pointing it out. As for the c++ code here's a tl;dr. We are suppose to learn pure C but the prof has C++ code in his lectures and notes. So unless its blatantly obvious (like std::vector), I can use some C++ function. I also saw someone mention a memory leak, how can I fix that?
Edit 2: Someone mentioned the use of new[] instead of malloc and another that I should have another free() for my second malloc. Can I simply change it to new[]? Will it still be a dynamic array? I can't seem to find new[] it my notes so I search for it, but I just need confirmation that this is what I'm trying to do. I also changed the 2 problematic lines thanks to someone's insight. Thanks a lot.

Context: this is for a small assignment for university. I'm trying to get a word as an input (e.g "Hello World!") which would then be transformed to remove consonants (e.g. "_e__o _o___!"). Everything is fine for now when it comes to swapping the letters in the array. The problem comes when I try to incorporate it in the main function. the function "wheelOfFortune" does its job but it doesn't seem to be passing the value to a_clue. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

//prototypes
char* wheelOfFortune(char* a_answer);
//This checks if the letter is a consonant. If it is, it replaces it with '_'
char convertChar(char letter, int isLowerCase);
//this was done for learning purposes. It simply identifies whether the letter is upper or lower case
int isLowerCase(char letter);

int main()
{
/*aWord should be a user input, but it's easier in terms of debugging if I put I automatically gave it values*/
char aWord[15];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(aWord); i++)
    {
        aWord[i] = 'a' + (i / 3);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < strlen(aWord); k++)
    {
        printf_s("%c", aWord[k]);
    }
    printf_s("\n");
    char* a_clue = wheelOfFortune(aWord); //This line has been edited
    printf_s("%s", a_clue);
    free(a_clue);
}

char* wheelOfFortune(char* a_answer)
{
    unsigned int numChar = strlen(a_answer);
    char* guessWord = (char*)malloc(strlen(a_answer));
    int numLowerCase = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        numLowerCase = isLowerCase(a_answer[i]);
        printf("%c\t", a_answer[i]);
        guessWord[i] = convertChar(a_answer[i], numLowerCase);
        printf("%c\t", guessWord[i]);
    }
    return guessWord;
}
```

I'm 99% sure the problem is with the lines "char* a_clue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aWord)); a_clue = wheelOfFortune(aWord);" but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Comment: `sizeof(a_answer)` doesn't do what you seem to think it does. hint: `strlen()`. why did you think `sizeof` was relevant here? edit: I guess because it does work for actual arrays, just not pointers.

Comment: `unsigned int numChar = sizeof(a_answer)`, is only going to be the size of the pointer, not the number of characters. Try `strlen` instead, or pass in the size of the array.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` instead and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Comment: `malloc` -- If you're going to do manual memory management in C++, use `new[]` instead of `malloc`.  Also, I know of no C++ book that shows usage of `malloc` (maybe `new[]`, but not `malloc`).  Are you reading `C` books and material instead of C++?

Comment: Once `char* a_answer` is a pointer, `sizeof(a_answer)` is usually 4 or 8 bytes. If you are writing in c++, use it. Instead of raw pointer, use `std::vector` or in this case, `std:: array`

Comment: It's also not clear why you tagged this as C++, since it looks completely like C, aside from the unused `#include <iostream>`. C++ has a vast standard library full of containers and other things that save you from raw code and rookie mistakes like this. Why not use them?

Comment: `char* a_clue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aWord));a_clue = wheelOfFortune(aWord);` -- Memory leak.

Comment: "I also saw someone mention a memory leak, how can I fix that?" The general rule of thumb is that every `malloc()` must have a corresponding `free()`. I see two `malloc()` calls in your code, but only one `free()`.

Comment: @Amadeus Did you mean "_don't_ use it"?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Hm.. I have changed the subject. What I mean was: If you are using C++, use the language and all the library that come with it (vector and arrays, for example)

Comment: @Amadeus Ah, I get it now :) I thought you meant "use `sizeof(a_answer)`" ;P

Answer (score 2):

> I also saw someone mention a memory leak, how can I fix that?

The general rule of thumb is that every `malloc()` must have a corresponding `free()`. I see two `malloc()` calls in your code, but only one `free()`. Closer inspection shows these two lines of code that cause a memory leak:

```
char* a_clue = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aWord));
a_clue = wheelOfFortune(aWord);
```

You first allocate a block of memory to assign to a pointer. Then you immediately assign that pointer to point at whatever is returned by `wheelOfFortune()`. You lose access to the original block of allocated memory. You should change this just to

```
char* a_clue = wheelOfFortune(aWord);
```